# VBA Adobe Acrobat Sub failing after being successful previously

Tags: vba, api, pdf, adobe

I have a subroutine that is in charge of combining 22 pdfs into 1. It grabs the first PDF in the list then loops through i+1 all the way to n (where n = 22), inserting those pages to the 1st PDF and then deleting the pdf at location i. So the final product is 1 PDF with all 22 pdfs combined inide of it, and the 22 pdfs get deleted to not bloat the file path. The crazy thing is while this script was working the entire time, it doesn't work anymore! The script skips out and exits the for loop without combining anything.

I've stepped through and have noticed that the **MergedDoc.GetNumPages()** call (that is found in the Interapplication API Docs for Adobe) is returning -1, so it is failing as per the docs..  As is the If **"MergedDoc.InsertPages... "** conditional statement, which exits the for..

But previously these things were not failing! Perhaps the document isn't being successfully opened in the .Open() call, but why would that be?

Does anybody have any idea what the issue could be? **I included Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library** in VBA from the tools -> reference window as well. I am also currently using Adobe Acrobat DC on my machine. The code is below and would love any input.

Thanks!

```
Sub MergePDFs(FileList As Variant)
    Dim i As Integer
    'Remember to include Acrobat (tools -> References)
    Dim AcroApp As Acrobat.CAcroApp
    Dim finalPath As String

    Dim numPages As Integer

    Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")

    Set MergedDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    Set DocToAdd = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

    finalPath = FileList(0)
    
    'open first file in PDF Array
    'MergedDoc.Open ("C:\Users\akhawaja\Documents\_a.pdf")
    MergedDoc.Open (finalPath)
    
    MsgBox "Files being combined to path: " & finalPath
    For i = LBound(FileList) + 1 To UBound(FileList)
        'Loop through 2nd - last.
        '1) Open & Get # of pages
        '2)Insert pages, Save, exit
        'MsgBox FileList(i)
        DocToAdd.Open (FileList(i))
        
        
        ' Insert the pages of Part2 after the end of Part1
        numPages = MergedDoc.GetNumPages()
        
        'MsgBox numPages
        'MsgBox DocToAdd.GetNumPages()
        
        If MergedDoc.InsertPages(numPages - 1, DocToAdd, 0, DocToAdd.GetNumPages(), 0) = False Then Exit For
            'MsgBox "Cannot insert pages at doc: " & FileList(i)
        'End If
        
        If MergedDoc.Save(PDSaveFull, finalPath) = False Then Exit For
        'MsgBox "Cannot save the modified document"
        'End If
    
        DocToAdd.Close
        
        'Delete PDF file now that is has been added
        Kill (FileList(i))
    Next i
    
    MergedDoc.Close
    AcroApp.Exit
    Set AcroApp = Nothing
    Set MergedDoc = Nothing
    Set DocToAdd = Nothing

    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Try putting a break on `numPages = MergedDoc.GetNumPages()` and wait a little while before continuing: does it then report the correct number of pages?

Comment: @TimWilliams Nope, after breaking it remains -1

Comment: Has the source of your PDF's changed?

Comment: @TimWilliams - Nope, the PDFs file location gets passed into the subroutine and they're created and when I add the FileList to the watch it is populated with valid file directory URLs

Comment: I meant where are the PDFs coming from? (ie. how are they produced, not what folder they're in)

Comment: @TimWilliams - The PDFS are generated from the excel sheet itself - I change the value of a cell (from 1-12 for each month), and save the pdf. These directories get saved to the FileList which is passed into this subroutine and from there it's supposed to be appended.

Comment: OK - I'm pretty much out of ideas.  Maybe if you know how many pages are in each PDF you could skip the `MergedDoc.GetNumPages()` part and supply the value directly?  Is it just these PDF's which fail to give the correct number of pages, or all PDF's you've tested?

Comment: @TimWilliams Just figurd it out - the path was being used as a OneDrive URL, when I changed the folder to a path with a C:\ url it ended up having no issues. Weird I know. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out - the path was being used as a OneDrive URL, when I changed the folder to a path with a C:\ url it ended up having no issues. Weird I know. Thanks for the help!